# VS 2013 Express project with NAudio and Midi.dll error loading winmm.dll (Windows 10)

Tags: c#, windows-10, midi, winmm

Hi there all of you :)

I have a big problem now. I wrote an audio application (using MIDI and NAudio libraries) in Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit and Visual Studio 2013 Express. Everything was OK. And then, funny me, upgraded my "lucky seven" to Windows 10 and installed same Visual Studio 2013 Express for Windows Desktop.

So, i opened my project, rebuilded and run... unfortunatelly i got creppy message with some kind of error / exception / about winmm.dll from midi.dll

I can't figure it out what's going on. This makes me big headache :(

[image]

[image]

Comment: 0x800700b6 =  ERROR_INVALID_ORDINAL. looks like Naudio uses Pinvoke and 1 import has changed in Win10.

Comment: magicandre1981 - thank you for the tip. Any advice / possibilities how to fix it? I'am still "a beginner" and never saw that kind of problem...till now.

Comment: step through the NAudio/Midi code and look for the code definition of the failing code and check MSDN docs if the method is defined correctly.

Comment: Thank you! I was not able to fix it with my knowledge now but i did something else. I removed whole Midi project from my solution and created it again with same reference to Midi.dll
It works. But a new problem appears. I think i have to write a new question about it.

Comment: ok, post your solution as answer and accept it. Yes, ask a 2nd question about your new issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little solution for my problem. I removed whole Midi project from my solution and created it again with same reference to Midi.dll
It works now.